# Real life uses of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand the geometric intuition behind determinants but what is the real life use of it? I'm not looking for answers along the lines of "it helps to find solutions to linear systems" etc, unless this is one of those concepts that is useful because it allows us to do "more math". I'm more interested in knowing practical applications of determinants in science, engineering, computer graphics etc.

Answer (score 2):

Area integrals and volume integrals over complicated areas or volumes (like spheres, balls, ellipses, hyperboloids, etc.) can be calculated using the transformation theorem, which is a generalization of integration by substitution. It uses the determinant of the differential/Jacobian of the coordinate transformation.

Examples for its use: wherever we calculate higher dimensional integrals, so essentially any and all fields of physics and engineering. Electrodynamics profiting especially, since its fundamental equations (Maxwell's equations) involve precisely such integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying, in the deformation theory of bodies, the determinant of the deformation tensor gives the ratio between the final volume, in the deformed state, and the initial volume, in the undeformed state. Then, if det > 0 (< 0), you have a deformation causing an expansion (contraction), whether if det = 0 there is no volume change during the deformation, a situation usually called distortion. This cannot be related to a particular reference system, then it has to be described by an invariant, as the determinant is.